# Returning Strict-Transport-Security includeSubdomains for a subdomain

Tags: hsts

Trying to find the answer and the spec doesn't actually seem to help.

The spec for HSTS says the following about the `includeSubdomains` flag:

```
includeSubDomains is a flag which, if present, signals to the UA that
                  the HSTS Policy applies to this HSTS Server as well
                  as any subdomains of the server's FQDN.
```

All the examples I've seen assume that the request goes to e.g. `example.com` (with no subdomain specified), so returning `includeSubdomains` will then make it apply to `www.example.com`, `api.example.com` etc. as well as to `example.com`.

Two questions:

1. If I return an HSTS header with `includeSubdomains` to a request to `www.example.com`, will it then apply to `www.example.com` and *all other subdomains*? It sounds like it does. Does it also apply to the top-level `example.com`?
2. If I return the HSTS header in a request to `www.example.com` and I **don't** include the `includeSubdomains` flag, will the HSTS header apply **only** to `www.example.com`, or will it also apply to `example.com`?

For instance, could I return one HSTS header for requests to `www.example.com` and another HSTS header (perhaps with a different max-age value) to `api.example.com`? If I returna  header to requests to `example.com` which has `includeSubdomains` specified, what takes priority - the subdomain-specific HSTS header or the global header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I return an HSTS header with includeSubdomains to a request to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), will it then apply to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and all other subdomains? It sounds like it does. Does it also apply to the top-level example.com?

No, it will apply to all sub domains of the domain it’s set for. For example sub.www.example.com. It will NOT apply to any sibling domains (e.g. api.example.com), nor the parent domain (example.com). The `includeSubdomains` flag is for going further down - not for going back up, or sideways.

For that reason many sites recommend loading something from the top level domain to pick up the top level HSTS policy (s.g. https://example.com/pixel.png) and so protect the whole site including sibling domains. This works even if the request 301s to the www variant (https://example.com/pixel.png) — if the 301 includes the HSTS header, as that’s enough for the browser to see the top level policy.

> If I return the HSTS header in a request to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I don't include the `includeSubdomains` flag, will the HSTS header apply only to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), or will it also apply to example.com?

Any HSTS header for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) has no impact on example.com. It only applies for the www domain (and potentially sub domains depending on the presence only the `includeSubdomains` header).

> For instance, could I return one HSTS header for requests to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and another HSTS header (perhaps with a different max-age value) to api.example.com?

Yup they are completely independent.

> If I returna header to requests to example.com which has includeSubdomains specified, what takes priority - the subdomain-specific HSTS header or the global header?

The sub domain specific one takes priority. However if the sub domain specific one expires without being reset, then it no longer exists, so the base level domain policy then kicks into place.